# Does GraphQL ever redundantly visit fields during execution?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I was reading [this](https://blog.apollographql.com/graphql-explained-5844742f195e) article and it used the following query:

```
{
  getAuthor(id: 5){
    name
    posts {
      title
      author {
        name # this will be the same as the name above
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which was parsed and turned into an AST like the one below: 
[image: this pic]

Clearly it is bringing back redundant information (the Author's name is asked for twice), so I was wondering how GraphQL Handles that. Does it redundantly fetch that information? Is the diagram a proper depiction of the actual AST?

Any insight into the query parsing and execution process relevant to this would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: I know this may vary depending on the actual implementation of the GraphQl server, but I was wondering what the standard / best practice was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, GraphQL may fetch the same information multiple times in this scenario. GraphQL does not memoize the resolver function, so even if it is called with the same arguments and the same parent value, it will still run again.

This is a fairly common problem when working with databases in GraphQL. The most common solution is to utilize [DataLoader](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader), which not only batches your database requests, but also provides a cache for those requests for the duration of the GraphQL request. This way, even if a particular record is requested multiple times, it will only be fetched from the database once.

The alternative (albeit more complicated) approach is to compose a single database query based on the requested fields that executes at the root level. For example, our resolver for `getAuthor` could constructor a single query that would return the author, their posts and each of that post's author. With this approach, we can skip writing resolvers for the `posts` field on the `Author` type or the `author` field on the `Post` type and just utilize the default resolver behavior. However, in order to do this and avoid overfetching, we have to parse the GraphQL request inside the `getAuthor` resolver in order to determine which fields were requested and should therefore be included in our database query.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When you said "compose a single database query based on the requested fields that executes at the root level" I'm assuming you mean we would have to parse the query and construct the AST differently so as to avoid redundant nodes? Does any GraphQL client do this?

Comment: Sorry, that's not quite what I meant. I could have been clearer. You wouldn't avoid redundant nodes, you would just utilize a single database query that would capture all relevant nodes. I edited my answer to elaborate more.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!